# passing URL variables to php when the link clicked

Tags: php, url

I have URL in this from: `locahhost/index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=xxxxx&tv_id=xxx&tid=xxxx&channel=x`

when the user click this link, the file `index1.php` should process this the URL then produce

new URL in this form localhost/static/popups/xxxxxxxxxxx.html wher xxxxxxxxxxxxx is the

event_id, tv_id, tid and chanel.

to do this I am using parse url function in the file `index1.php` as following :

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=&tv_id=&tid=&channel=';
$parsed = parse_url( $url );
parse_str( $parsed['query'], $data );
$newurl = 'http://localhost.eu/static/popups/'.$data['event_id'].$data['tv_id'].$data['tid'].$data['channel'].'.html';
header("Location: $newurl");
?>
```

but its not working i think this is due to something wrong in  `$url = 'http://localhost/index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=&tv_id=&tid=&channel=';`

what is wrong with this? also i want it when for example tv_id not present in the url it put instead 0 in the newurl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://localhost/index1.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&event_id=&tv_id=&tid=&channel=';
$parsed = parse_url( $url );
parse_str( $parsed['query'], $data );

$keys = array('event_id', 'tv_id', 'tid', 'channel'); // order does matter
$newurl = 'http://localhost.eu/static/popups/';
foreach ($keys as $key)
    $newurl.= empty($data[$key])?0:$data[$key];

$newurl.='.html';

echo $newurl;
```

returns:

```
http://localhost.eu/static/popups/0000.html
```

---

UPDATE:
You do not need to make an $url variable and parse it into an array of values.
When user clicks a link data comes with `GET` method. If you use `GET` or `POST` instead of $url, just use $_REQUEST['variable'] (or $_GET[''] or $_POST[''])

```
$keys = array('event_id', 'tv_id', 'tid', 'channel'); // order does matter
$newurl = 'http://localhost.eu/static/popups/';
foreach ($keys as $key)
    $newurl.= empty($_REQUEST[$key])?0:$_REQUEST[$key];

$newurl.='.html';

echo $newurl;
```

Comment: @ Andrey volk your code is very good, but one problem is there, how to transfer these values `event_id', 'tv_id', 'tid', 'channel` from the link that user click on to the $url.

Comment: very good it works awsome and the job done thank u . another help from u sir assuming the new url will be `http://remotesite.com/static/popups/xxxxxxxxxxxx.html` and instead of echo that url i need to get the source code of it and create new html file with the same name of xxxxxxxxxxxx.html in the following path mydomain/static/popups and redirect the user to this file

Comment: Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: yes i am confused how to use file put contents but i use its identical  `fopen(), fwrite() and fclose()` but my problem is about the file name as you know it will be differnet every time xxxxxxxxx.html i dont know how to write this in the code ? but thank u at last you have solved my probelm that was distrubing me for three days as ia m newbie

Answer (score 1):

`$newUrl` is malformed.  you're missing a close-bracket `]` after `$data['tv_id'`.

`$newurl = 'http://localhost.eu/static/popups/'.$data['event_id'].$data['tv_id'.$data['tid'].$data['channel'].'.html';`

Answer (score 0):

The parse_url function is to take a given URL and turn it into its constituent parts.
What you're looking for is to access variables from the $_GET array.

I'll assume your event ID is an integer

```
$event_id=(int)$_GET['event_id'];
$new_url=''http://localhost.eu/static/'.$event_id // and so forth
```

If you expect text instead of numbers in one of your variables, do some more sanitzation on it.

Comment: everyone this just missed here when posting the question but i already closed the bracket when trying my question is whole about the $url i think the code miss something the pull the variables from the url clicked  by the user to transfer him the the correct new url

Comment: In the popoup url, are there any seperators between the values?

Comment: @user2338253 you might want to edit your question to include the missing bracket, so we're not thrown off the track by it.

Comment: here is where i went with your code `<?php
$event_id=(int)$_GET['event_id'];
$tv_id=(int)$_GET['tv_id'];
$tid=(int)$_GET['tid'];
$channel=(int)$_GET['channel'];
$new_url=''http://localhost.eu/static/'.$event_id.$tv_id.$t1id.$channel.'.html''
echo $new_url
?>` but not working is this right?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close the tv_id array tag in $new_url

```
$newurl = 'http://localhost.eu/static/popups /'.$data['event_id'].$data['tv_id'].$data['tid'].$data['channel'].'.html';
```